# Get id from database in context menu

Tags: android, android-layout

hi am really struck with this question. I'm new in android world.I have a list which display info from database.(id , name and description). On click and hold operation i want to delete selected row from database. I already implemented the context menu but am not getting the id from database but returns position (0 but id from db is 1).thanx

i think i got it :)

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    TextView ids = (TextView)findViewById(R.layout.list_row);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;
    int foldeiId=(Integer) adapter.getItem(position);
    String fd = String.valueOf(view.getId());
    // Log.w("Data id arunmr: ", foldeiId);
    System.out.println(foldeiId);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ITEM, foldeiId, "Delete");
    menu.add(0, SAVE_MENU_ITEM, foldeiId, "Rename");
}
```

but any idea how to access the mentioned "foldeiId"  from context menu ?

Comment: what data you are displaying on the list?

Comment: id , item name and item description . I want to get the id

Comment: how are you displaying it in the listview? Can you post the sample code of how you are adding and displaying it

Comment: i think i got solution :) see edited question

Comment: no this wont be the solution always (i think) because when you delete a particular item from the database then the particular id gets deleted which means you will not be having the item in the database

Comment: make int foldeiId; global. 
This will allow you to get the variable accesible even in the context menu

Comment: can u tell me  menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ITEM, foldeiId, "Delete"); from this how i can access "foldeiId" in context menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
       You can get the foldeiId if you declare that variable outside the oncreate() method

```
@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){
        // delete the item you want to delete
}  
else if(item.getTitle()=="Rename"){
      // rename the item you want to 
}  
else {return false;}  
return true;  
}
```